# Using Swift generics in a RxSwift getter function - various problems

Tags: swift, generics, rx-swift

Here's the function:

```
func registerFor<Element>(relayId id: String) -> Driver<Element>? {
    guard let relay = relays[id] as? BehaviorRelay<Element> else { return nil }
    return relay.asObservable()
        .distinctUntilChanged { a, b in
            return a != b
        }.flatMapLatest { value in
            return Observable.create { observer in
                observer.on(.next(value))
                return Disposables.create()
            }
        }.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: Element())
}
```

The `distinctUntilChanged` line throws the following error:

```
Contextual closure type '(Element) throws -> _' expects 1 argument, 
but 2 were used in closure body
```

The `asDriver` line throws the following error (of course):

```
Non-nominal type 'Element' does not support explicit initialization
```

Context: I have a class that ideally has a collection of `BehaviorRelay`s of various types (Strings, Ints, etc). `Element` stands in generically for these types, but that creates two problems:

1. `distinctUntilChanged` insists of having a closure (eg: if this method returned `Driver<String>` it would be content simply to use `distinctUntilChanged()` but the generic `Element` makes it complain about missing a closure);
2. `onErrorJustReturn` requires a concrete value, but `Element` is generic.

The following "workaround" might work but I suspect there are better solutions

```
protocol Inii {
    init()
}

func registerFor(relayId id: String, def: Inii.Type) -> Driver<Inii>? {
    return relays[id]?.asObservable()
        .distinctUntilChanged { _, _ in
            return true
        }.flatMapLatest { value in
            return Observable.create { observer in
                observer.on(.next(value))
                return Disposables.create()
            }
        }.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: def.init())
}
```

Although I'm still unsure what to put in the `distinctUntilChanged` closure.

---

**Appendix A**

I believe that the following is what is required if one is implementing the `distinctUntilChanged` closure for a non-generic type:

```
.distinctUntilChanged { previousValue, currentValue in
    return previousValue == currentValue
}
```

However, when used with the generic `Element` the following error is still thrown:

```
Contextual closure type '(Inii) throws -> _' expects 1 argument, 
but 2 were used in closure body
```

---

**Appendix B**

Here's another alternative with a slightly different problem:

```
protocol Inii {
    init()
}

var relay = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")

func registerFor<Element>(def: Element.Type) -> Driver<Element> where Element: Inii {
    return relay.asObservable()
        .distinctUntilChanged { previousValue, currentValue in
            return previousValue == currentValue
        }.flatMapLatest { value in
            return Observable.create { observer in
                observer.on(.next(value))
                return Disposables.create()
            }
        }.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: def.init())
}
```

Error in this case being:

```
Member 'next' in 'Event<_>' produces result of type 'Event<Element>', 
but context expects 'Event<_>'
```

at the `observer.on` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinctUntilChanged()` without a closure as long as `Element` conforms to `Equatable`:

```
protocol EmptyInit {
    init()
}

func registerFor<Element>(relayId id: String) -> Driver<Element>? where Element: Equatable, Element: EmptyInit {
    guard let relay = relays[id] as? BehaviorRelay<Element> else { return nil }
    return relay.asObservable()
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMapLatest { value in
            return Observable.create { observer in
                observer.on(.next(value))
                return Disposables.create()
            }
        }.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: Element())
}
```